# Why can't I get vim-better-whitespace to highlight trailing whitespace for me?

Tags: vim

I've confirmed that I've installed the plugin, and commands such as :StripWhitespace work fine. For some reason, I just can't get trailing whitespace highlighted.

All my vim files, including the git submodule for vim-better-whitespace, are in a public repo here: https://github.com/AnselAtoms/dev_env

Comment: Have you executed: `:ToggleWhitespace`? Is your background color clashing with your `ExtraWhitespace` color? You can set this via `highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=<desired_color>`. Please see [vim-better-whitespace](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace) homepage for more information.

Comment: Peter, I added this line to my color theme and now it works: hi ExtraWhitespace guibg=#990000 ctermbg=red. Would you like to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be a few issues:

- You may have to enable the plugin via `:ToggleWhitespace`
- The highlight group that the plugin uses may be blending in with your colorscheme or may not be providing a color for your terminal's color depth. Try using: `hi ExtraWhitespace guibg=#990000 ctermbg=red`. See `:h :hi` for more highlight information.

The [vim-better-whitespace](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace) homepage for more information on how to setup and use the plugin. You can also use `:h better-whitespace`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the ExtraWhitespace property default wasn't being applied, but adding it in manually to my theme did the trick. Thanks!